# Histogram Values Distorted When Using `ppc_stat()`

Tags: r, plot, statistics, histogram, stan

I am using the following data:

```
speed <- c(28, 26, 33, 24, 34, -44, 27, 16, 40, -2, 29, 22, 24, 21, 25, 30, 23, 29, 31, 19, 24, 20, 36, 32, 36, 28, 25, 21, 28, 29, 37, 25, 28, 26, 30, 32, 36, 26, 30, 22, 36, 23, 27, 27, 28, 27, 31, 27, 26, 33, 26, 32, 32, 24, 39, 28, 24, 25, 32, 25, 29, 27, 28, 29, 16, 23)
```

My current Stan code is as follows:

````
```{stan output.var="NMM_PPD"}
data{
  int<lower=1> n;
  vector[n] y;
  real<lower=0> nu;
}

parameters{
  real y_mu;
  real y_sd;
}

model{
  y ~ student_t(nu, y_mu, y_sd);
  y_mu ~ normal(0, 1000);
  y_sd ~ cauchy(0, 5);
}

generated quantities{
  vector[n] y_rep;

  for(i in 1:n){
    y_rep[i] = student_t_rng(nu, y_mu, y_sd);
  }
}
```
````

And I pass in values of `nu` and draw samples from the model using the following code:

````
```{r}
data.in <- list(y=speed, n=length(speed), "nu" = 1)
model.fit <- sampling(NMM_PPD, data=data.in)
```
````

We use the `extract()` function to extract our replicated data sets from the `model.fit` object:

````
```{r}
yrep <- extract(model.fit, pars = "y_rep")[[1]]
```
````

I now plot the histograms:

````
```{r}
ppc_hist(speed, yrep[sample(NROW(yrep), 11), ])
```
````

[image]

````
```{r}
ppc_dens(speed, yrep[sample(NROW(yrep), 2), ])
```
````

[image]

````
```{r}
ppc_dens_overlay(speed, yrep[sample(NROW(yrep), 11), ])
```
````

[image]

````
```{r}
ppc_stat(speed, yrep)
```
````

[image]

````
```{r}
ppc_stat(speed, yrep, stat = "median")
```
````

[image]

````
```{r}
ppc_stat(speed, yrep, stat = "max")
```
````

[image]

````
```{r}
ppc_stat(speed, yrep, stat = "min")
```
````

[image]

Notice that some of these histograms are distorted due to the presence of small and large values. I would like to fix this distortion so that I can visually see the histogram values.

I see nothing in the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bayesplot/versions/1.5.0/topics/PPC-test-statistics) for `ppc_stat()` that would allow us to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`ppc_stat()` returns a ggplot object so you can modify it as you would a ggplot plot. You might want to be careful with just putting arbitrary limits on the scales though as there is data out there on the edges just not a lot. You can also use a pseudo log transform. This shows to do both:

```
ppc_hist(speed, yrep[sample(NROW(yrep), 11), ]) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-100,100), trans='pseudo_log')
ppc_stat(speed, yrep, stat = "min") + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-10000,100), trans='pseudo_log')
```